# What error code should I use for the Edge vs IE

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, msdn

ALL,

The error codes listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775145(v=vs.85)

are for IE which is outdated.

Is there a documentation in MSDN what they are mapped to for the Edge?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

I searched but don't find such doc for Edge. I think Edge doesn't support it.

[URL Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/url-monikers) is a COM object which can be applied with old IE MSHTML kernel, but it doesn't have an interface for Edge which is based on chromium.